# Не работает Functions.php дочерней темы

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, themes

Создаю сайт на wordpress, тема onepress. Создал дочернюю тему. Как выяснилось не работает файл functions.php . Вставлял разные функции(копипаст из интернета), ни одна не работает. В чем причина?

```css
/*
 Theme Name:   OnePress Child
 Theme URI:    https://www.famethemes.com
 Description:  OnePress sample child theme
 Author:       FameThemes
 Author URI:   https://www.famethemes.com
 Template:     onepress
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  onepress-child
*/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите заголовок style.css и расположение папок

Comment: Все правильно, должно работать. А что у вас в functions.php? Вставьте просто `echo 'aaaaaaaaaa';` в самое начало, после `<?php` для проверки

Answer (score 2):

Конфигурация дочерней темы:

onepress-child

- [style.css](https://prnt.sc/jpzmh5)
- [functions.php](https://prnt.sc/jpzmsv)

Содержимое:

- style.css

  ```
  /*
  Theme Name: OnePress Child
  Author: Eugene V.
  Description: OnePress Child Theme
  Template: onepress
  Version: 1.0.0
  Tags: one-column, two-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, custom-menu, featured-images, full-width-template, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready, e-commerce, blog, portfolio
  */
  .site {
      color: #555!important;
  }
  ```
- functions.php

  ```
  <?php

      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_styles' );

      function custom_enqueue_styles() {  
          wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
      }

      register_nav_menus(
          array(
              'main_menu'  => __( 'Main Menu', 'onepress' ),
              'footer_menu'  => __( 'Footer Menu', 'onepress' )
          )   
      );
  ```

Проверяйте у себя, что-то вы делаете не так.